# Dialogflow assistant app exiting after successful fulfillment

Tags: webhooks, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I have a dialogflow assistant app with 3 intents. The first intent asks the user for location and name details from google. I am using a webhook for the fulfillment of this intent. I am able to extract the user information name and location, but after it is showing output from webhook, it is exiting from flow. But it is supposed to pass the location parameters to next intent and stay on the flow. Can anybody help me how to stop assistant from exiting? 
Here is the webhook code 
[image]

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const DialogflowApp = require('actions-on-google').DialogflowApp;

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

    const requestPermission = (app) => {
      app.askForPermissions('To report ', [app.SupportedPermissions.NAME, app.SupportedPermissions.DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION]);
    };

    const userInfo = (app) => {
        if (app.isPermissionGranted()) {
            const address = app.getDeviceLocation().coordinates;
            const name = app.getUserName().givenName;
            if (name) {            
                app.tell(`You are name ${name}`);
            }
            else {
                // Note: Currently, precise locaton only returns lat/lng coordinates on phones and lat/lng coordinates 
                // and a geocoded address on voice-activated speakers. 
                // Coarse location only works on voice-activated speakers.
                app.tell('Sorry, I could not figure out where you are.Plaese try again');
            }
        } else {
            app.tell('Sorry, I could not figure out where you are.Please try again');
        }
    };

    const app = new DialogflowApp({request, response});
    const actions = new Map();
    actions.set('request_permission', requestPermission);
    actions.set('user_info', userInfo);
    app.handleRequest(actions);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are calling `app.tell()` in your code which is a signal to the Assistant to send the message and then end the conversation.

If you want to send the message and then leave the microphone open for the user to reply, you should use `app.ask()` instead. It takes the same parameters - the only difference is that it expects the user to reply.

So that portion of your code might look something like

```
        if (name) {            
            app.ask(`You are name ${name}. What would you like to do now?`);
        }
```

(You should make sure that the prompt for the user is one that they will expect to reply. The review process will reject your Action if you reply and it isn't obvious that the user is supposed to reply to you.)